# WHERE clause on a TIMESTAMP column causes serious performance penalty

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count, timestamp

I have a `pages` and a `page_views` tables with 100k~ & 4M~ records respectively.

I run a query to get the top pages that have the most page_views:

```
    select `pages`.`id`, `pages`.`host`, `pages`.`embed_code_id`, `views`.`count` 
from `pages` 
inner join `embed_codes` on `pages`.`embed_code_id` = `embed_codes`.`id` 
inner join (
    select `page_id`, COUNT(*) AS count 
    from `page_views` 
    where `page_views`.`created_at` between '2018-12-25 13:20:35' and '2018-12-26 13:20:35' 
    group by `page_id`
    ) as views on `views`.`page_id` = `pages`.`id` 
where `embed_codes`.`id` in (512) 
and `embed_codes`.`account_id` = 173
order by `views`.`count` desc 
limit 6
```

This query takes more than 9 seconds to run, but when i remove the `WHERE` clause on `page_views`.`created_at`, it takes only 700ms~, which is acceptable i guess, given the tables sizes.

NOTE - `page_views.created_at` is indexed.

Any ideas why the WHERE clause is causing this slowness? Any way to avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you try the DATETIME  in where clause.

Comment: What is O.S environment?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to see the indexes, the datatypes of other columns in the `WHERE`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with the WHERE condition the system is searching by the index on 'created_at' and when you eliminate this condition it searches by 'page_id'.
if you add a new composed index on 'page_id' and 'created_at' or in the other order, the optimizer possibly will find the correct execution plan.

Comment: An Index on page_id AND created_at worked, thanks! (now apx. 500ms)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes needed:

```
page_views:  (created_at, page_id)  -- in this order
pages:       (id)   -- probably already the PRIMARY KEY?
embed_codes: (id)   -- probably already the PRIMARY KEY?
```

If there are still issues after adding those indexes, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

[*indexing cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: thank, an index on created_at & page_id did solved the issue